# How to identify non static tomcat requests

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I would like to add logging of requests and responses to a Java webapp which I am running within Tomcat 6. My webapp serves up a mixture of static files and dynamic content generated by servlets. I only want to log the requests and responses which are handled by my servlets.

I thought the best approach to implement the logging would be to use a Filter to capture the incoming HttpServletRequest and wrap the HttpServletResponse to allow the response content to be captured.

Is there a way to tell in a Tomcat Filter which servlet is going to handle the incoming HttpServletRequest? The best idea I've had so far is to parse the web.xml file and extract a mapping from  elements to servlets. I could then examine the path of the incoming request to work out which servlet will handle it. If it isn't the Tomcat DefaultServlet then I would log the request.

This feels a bit awkward as Tomcat has already done all this parsing of web.xml so I was hoping there is some kind of existing API to query that parsed information.

Comment: the information is available with Servlet 3. However that requires tomcat 7

Comment: I'm stuck on Tomcat 6 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on Tomcat 7; and while the annotations new to the servlet 3.0 api might make this easier; it should still be possible to do what you're talking about on Tomcat 6.  Since you've got the basic concept of filtering down I won't cover that but you should be able to declare your filter-mappings in such a way that they only get applied to specific servlets.  Looking at the web.xml from the example I found [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2009/10/sample-webxml-servlet-25.html):

```
<filter>
   <display-name>Filter1</display-name>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <filter-class>Filter1</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/Filter1</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <!-- declaring which servlet to filter here...... -->
   <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
```

I hope that works.  I'm working on filters too; so if it doesn't let me know and I'll spend some more time looking into it since I've got to do something like this anyways....

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I didn't know that I could map a filter to a servlet. However, ideally I would like to avoid having to list all my servlets as there are quite a few in my webapp and other developers might add more and not know about the list in the <filter-mapping>. What I really want is a mechanism to exclude particular servlets rather than include particular servlets.

Comment: I ended up listing all the servlets. Its not pretty but it works.